# Select the rows of a text file based on the values in the column

Tags: bash, text, awk

In my text file, I have something like below and I want to select the rows in which the second column has the value of "1".

```
flower   1    12
tree     2    13
car      3    14
sun      1    20
```

I have tried something like this: `awk -F, 'int($1) == 1' test.txt > output.txt` and the output was empty. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in awk should be loke:

```
awk ' $2=="1" {print}' test.txt >output.txt
```